# how to generate custom code symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using symfony 2 with doctrine. I want to create custom id for the product table.

Eg:

Product code 
P1000-1
P1000-2
P1000-3

How to generate this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you write a small piece of custom function to retrieve the last inserted ID and then add 'P1000-' before the id. See below,

```
public function getLastInsertedId($entity)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $result = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $last_inserted_id = $result->select('MAX(p.id) as id')
            ->from($entity, 'p')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);        
    return 'P1000-'.$last_inserted_id['id'];
}
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers!

Comment: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Test\Bundle\Entity\Product::getDoctrine() 
I got this error

Comment: You need to be in a Controller to create this function. $this->getDoctrine() is accessible via Controller or any class which extends it.

Comment: How to execute query from entity class then ?

Comment: You can inject the doctrine manager to your entity class from the services.yml file. You can see more on dependency injection from here :- http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

if it's sequential, you can try [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#generatedvalue.)

If you need more flexibility , you have to use a custom Id Generator. Create a class which extends [AbstractIdGenerator](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Id.AbstractIdGenerator.html) and implement the `generate()` method, as per your requirement.

and in your entity, use the following Annotations .

```
 @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="\Some\Bundle\Util\CustomGenerator")
```

on the Id Field , make sure the `generate()` method returns the same type as that used in the field .

Comment: How to add this to orm.yml file ?

Can I create a function on entity class that gets last inserted id and concat with some value and set value to that column ?

Comment: @Vamshi is there any guideline for that...Since I'm new to symfony framework